# Javascript - JSON.parse: unexpected end of data - Error when using valid JSON. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

So, I've found similar questions about JQuery in which you do not need to parse. Since I am using the AJAX XMLHttpRequest, from what I understand, the parse is necessary. The error is given on the line:

```
text = JSON.parse(jsonGet.responseText);
```

Error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected end of data  
text = JSON.parse(jsonGet.responseText);
```

Relevant parts of the function:

```
function populateList(){
//retrieves list from the server, adds it to the option box
    if(toggle == 0){
        var jsonGet = new XMLHttpRequest();
        jsonGet.open("GET","./json/GetAllEvents.php",true);
        jsonGet.onreadystatechange = function () {
                text = JSON.parse(jsonGet.responseText);   //ERROR HERE
                //updating html with data received
        };
        jsonGet.send();
        toggle = 1;
    } else {}

};
```

The JSON returned looks like this (without the line breaks):

```
{"success":true,
"number_of_rows":2,
"data":[
    {"id":"7","event_name":null,"day":3,"start_time":510,"end_time":617},
    {"id":"8","event_name":null,"day":1,"start_time":510,"end_time":617}
]}
```

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says that the above is valid. I guess I will take a look into whether XMLHttpRequest does anything strange. Firefox continues to function (even though firebug shows the error), IE9 stops at this point though.

I'm pretty stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check if `jsonGet.readyState==4 && jsonGet.status==200` before parsing the response.

Comment: Awesome, jsonGet.readyState == 4 got rid of the error. Adding the status in though causes it not to execute. The status I'm getting in a test with a .json file is 0. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Using the actual .php file gives status 200. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! The zero status could be related to your webserver versus .json files.