# Process json array using Jquery and json syntax error

Tags: jquery, json, arrays

I want to process a `Json` array returned by `php` file. The `PHP` code is below.

```
$pdo = new PDO('');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'SELECT * from table';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) 
{
    $results[] = array('row1' =>$row['col1'],
    'row2' => $row['col2'],
    'row3' => $row['col3']);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
```

The above code will return `Json` array like this one

```
[
   {"row1":"test","row2":"5.123456","row3":"6.123456"},
   {"row1":"test1","row2":"6.123456","row3":"8.123654"},
   {"row1":"test3","row2":"6.321456","row3":"8.964512"}
]
```

I want to process the above `Json` array and present it inside a table. I try many `Jquery` codes and spent hours in front of computer. But i can't get correct answer. Please help me. Help me by either give correct `Jquery` code to process the `Json` array or give correct `PHP` code to send correct `Json` string. I forgot to say another info. When I try to debug using FF, I am getting an error in console

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnLcZ.jpg

(image shows: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data)

**UPDATE**

I update your script like this. The script return nothing. Please help

```
var html="<table border=1 style='border-collapse:collapse'>";
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
   url: "http://10.44.0.160/service.php",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   type: "POST",
success: function(data) 
{
data.forEach(function(obj,index){html+="<tr><td>"+index+"<td>"+obj.csc_name+"</td><td>"+obj.lat+"</td><td>"+obj.longi+"</td></tr>";});
html+="</table>";
jQuery(html).appendTo("body");
}
            });
        });
```

Comment: try looking at ExtJS , it accepts the data as JSON , will display in whatever format you want

Comment: `I try many Jquery codes and spent hours in front of computer.` Could you please post some of your attempts?

Comment: All of them are from stackoverflow. Please see the link. I have an error in consol also

Answer (score 0):

use each to loop throw your json data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.each(yourData, function(key, val) {

           //your code here
           alert(key + '=' + val)

     });
 </script>
```

Comment: I am totally new to JS. Please post full code. Also see the update (Image Link) on my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html="<table border=1 style='border-collapse:collapse'>";

var json=[
 {"row1":"test","row2":"5.123456","row3":"6.123456"},
 {"row1":"test1","row2":"6.123456","row3":"8.123654"},
 {"row1":"test3","row2":"6.321456","row3":"8.964512"}
];
json.forEach(function(obj,index){html+="<tr><td>"+index+"<td>"+obj.row1+"</td>    <td>"+obj.row2+"</td><td>"+obj.row3+"</td></tr>";});
html+="</table>";
jQuery(html).appendTo("body");
```

Check out this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/TdM8s/

Comment: Thanks friend, it's working. This is the code I need. Please post full code ie, ajax request to server + jquery parser (Your Code). Why I am getting error in FF console 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data'

Comment: It seems that you have trouble getting data from server try using console.log(data) before using it. Also check out the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321510/javascript-json-parse-unexpected-end-of-data-error-when-using-valid-json-w